# Can you change IIS application settings from cmd?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I'm looking at setting an IIS application setting through a script of some sorts, and I've been looking into appcmd.exe, but I can't quite tell whether I'm able to make the change I need to with this.

Anyways, I have an Server 2016 RDWeb instance running, and I'd like to be able to set the PasswordChangeEnabled setting from False to True. While I can do this from the IIS manager GUI with ease, I need to be able to do this from command prompt.

The setting is under [Server Name] –> Sites –> Default Web Site –> RDWeb –> Pages and open the section Application Settings.

Is this possible to achieve using appcmd??

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801199/appcmd-set-config-appsettings-value-with-plus-is-being-converting-to-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using powershell, I had accomplished the same task, but other attribute, in the past.

`Get-IISConfigSection`

`Set-IISConfigAttributeValue`

Unfortunately I don't have an IIS available now to find the exact command. Check this also:

[MS IIS administration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/set-iisconfigattributevalue?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell command to enable the password change page is:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\RDweb\Pages' -Filter "/appSettings/add[@key='PasswordChangeEnabled']" -Name 'Value' -Value 'true'
```